# Firebase onAuthStateChanged error with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to check if a user is logged in or not on my React webpage using Firebase, however I keep getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'onAuthStateChanged' of undefined`, the line of code it links to is as followed:

Login.js:

```
authListener() {
Fire.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    this.setState({ user })
  } else {
    this.setState({ user: null })
  }
})}
```

Fire.js:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

const config = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    databaseURL: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "xxx"
};
const Fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default Fire;
```

** solved it, above is what my Fire.js and Login.js look like for those coming and having the same problem **

Comment: I think it should be `Fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged` instead of `Fire.auth.onAuthStateChanged`

Comment: I've tried that, it returns `TypeError: _Fire__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.auth is not a function`

Comment: What does `Fire` hold? From where you imported this? Could you share the code of `fire.js` file?

Comment: I edited my original post to show what is in Fire.js

Answer (score 3):

You need to include firebase package

```
import firebase from "firebase";
```

and then use **auth()** function of firebase

```
authListener() {
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    this.setState({ user })
  } else {
    this.setState({ user: null })
  }
})}
```

if you are importing firebase from another file then configure it like this

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
export const init = () => {
    let config = {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
};

export const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth;
```

Comment: I can't `import firebase from "firebase";` in another file called `Fire.js` and then import `Fire.js` and use `Fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged()`?